# When does Jesus not heal?

Tags: luke, mark, healing, miracle

It seems Jesus does not heal everyone.

> Mark 6:5 And he could there **do no mighty work**, save that he laid his hands upon a few sick folk, and healed them.

So also in Luke:

> Luke 5:15  But so much the more the report went abroad concerning him; and great multitudes gathered to hear and to be healed of their infirmities. 16 **But he withdrew** to the wilderness and prayed.

It seems Jesus does not heal everyone. The question in its simplest form: When does Jesus not heal?

Comment: Related: "[Did Jesus not heal the crippled beggar at the gate Beautiful?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/1707/)" Possible duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is in the next verse. Mark 6.6 says that he marvelled at their unbelief. Whenever Jesus healed someone, we hear him say" your faith has made you well". The healing anointing of Jesus was released when those people had faith. To be accurate, their faith became a sort of receptor device,through which they received their healing. People in this particular instance were offended at Jesus, and filled with unbelief. Maybe that is why he went around that area teaching, as hearing the word produces faith( romans10.17)

Answer (score 0):

In Matthew 10:1, Jesus sent out the Twelve with authority to drive out evil spirits and to cure every kind of disease and sickness. The ability gives the Twelve credibility. Their authority confirms them as messengers and confirms their message. Their message; "the kingdom of heaven is near," is shown to be from God by their healing powers. Jesus performed "signs and wonders" to confirm his authority.  In Mark 2:10, Jesus heals to show that he has the authority to forgive sins.